# How do I check if a variable contains a letter/phrase in batch?

Tags: batch-file

So I'm making, like, a fake messenger thing in batch to mess with people and I want to make it seem more realistic. Basically, I need to be able to search a variable to see if it contains a word? if that makes sense. Everyone that I've asked has said to use the findstr function, but I can't really do that because it's not a separate text file.

I was wondering if there was a way to do, like,

```
set /p input=thing (a variable for user input)
if %thing% contains "o" echo yes
```

I don't know if that makes sense. Sorry. I'm a beginner.

Thank you so much for reading this. I've been looking at stuff for this for like 3 hours

Comment: My advice is to use `findstr` if you have anything other than a standard alphanumeric string, (findstr does not need to read from a file). If its a basic alpanumeric string you could probably use an if comparison with substring replacement. So in the case of your example above, `If /I Not "%input:o=%" == "%input%" Echo %input% contains the character o`.

Comment: I would strongly advise however, that you do not rely on a Windows [tag:batch-file], `Set /P`, or [tag:findstr] for your task. `Set /P` accepts anything or nothing, including poisonous characters, and non secure input, whereas `findstr.exe` does not use a robust regular expression mechanism.

Comment: `FINDSTR` also reads from STDIN.  So you can pipe one command to another and use conditional execution or the errorlevel to tell you if it found the string.

Answer (score 1):

`findstr` works, but you have to consider everything. For instance:

```
findstr /irc:"hi"
```

will find the word `Hi` any string, but it will also find `high`, `which` etc. So it will take a lot of time and effort to get the responses close to 100%.. anyway, all just for fun. Give this a try.

```
@echo off
cls
set /p "you=What is your name? "
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "cn=0"
for %%i in (Mary Catlin John Steve Emma Candice) do (
    set /a cn+=1
    set "name[!cn!]=%%i"
    echo !cn!. %%i
)
for /l %%a in (1,1,!cn!) do set "ucount=!ucount!%%a"
choice /c !ucount! /m "Hi %you%, Who'd you like to chat to?"
set name=!name[%errorlevel%]!
echo Please wait for !name! to join.. & timeout /t 6 /nobreak>nul 2>&1 & echo !name! is online.

for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"
:chat
set /p "string=%you%: %ESC%[91m"
(timeout /t 1)>nul 2>&1
call :strings
goto :chat

:hi
echo %ESC%[92m!name!: What's up?%ESC%[0m
goto :eof

:doing
echo %ESC%[92m!name!: I am well, thank you%ESC%[0m
goto :eof

:time
echo %ESC%[92m!name!: It is now %time%%ESC%[0m
goto :eof

:date
echo %ESC%[92m!name!: The current date is %date%%ESC%[0m
goto :eof

:ben_jerry
echo %ESC%[92m!name!: I love Ben ^& Jerry's!!%ESC%[0m
goto :eof

:dude
echo %ESC%[92m!name!: DUDE!!%ESC%[0m
goto :eof

:not_love
echo %ESC%[92m!name!: WOAH!!! You're going to fast, I'm out%ESC%[0m
goto :eof

:strings
echo "%string%" | findstr /irc:"\<hi\>">nul 2>&1 && call :hi
echo "%string%" | findstr /irc:"\<how\>">nul 2>&1 && call :doing
echo "%string%" | findstr /irc:"\<time\>">nul 2>&1 && call :time
echo "%string%" | findstr /irc:"\<date\>">nul 2>&1 && call :date
echo "%string%" | findstr /irc:"\<love\>">nul 2>&1 && call :not_love
echo "%string%" | findstr /irc:"\<ben & jerry's\>">nul 2>&1 && call :ben_jerry
echo "%string%" | findstr /irc:"ice cream">nul 2>&1 && call :dude && call :ben_jerry
if "%string%" == "/exit" color & cls & exit
goto :eof
```

Result, where `me:` would be what I typed and `Bot: being the responses.
[image]

Comment: What happens if the end user enters `Ben & Jerry's ice cream`?

Comment: @Compo, indeed, but I am shoing OP some basics, so not even getting to special chacacters yet. Will see if I can do some updates quick.

Comment: TBF Gerhard, I asked the question because of my comments under the main question. Using `echo %string% | findstr …`, or probably better `echo(%string% | findstr …`, or possibly even better, `echo !string! | findstr …` will still not provide a fully robust mechanism. And if you doublequote `%string%`, or `!string!` what happens if the end user entered something like `my door is 30" wide`. Once you've catered for the `Set /P`, `findstr.exe`, and `cmd.exe` inadequacies, it becomes clear that using batch-files is the wrong idea completely.

Comment: @Gerhard: see `findstr` word boundary options. `\<hi\>` would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: @Compo, off course yes, I agree, it will not. If this was planned to be a production chat bot, then no, I would not have considered such a puny script, but OP seems to want it to "play around" so I am sure they will learn from it.

Comment: @Stephan, yeah, I kind off did not consider that at the time. but again, this is not meant to be a great "fake" chat, there can be numerous loopholes. Thanks.

Comment: @Compo I updated to cater for special characters, and added Ben & jerry's to the list for you.

Comment: @Gerhard Thank you so much for your help with this! I honestly didn't expect to get an answer, let alone an awesome one with an example. :)

Comment: @catlin, no problem, but you must consider all things that can go wrong, so play around with it and see what you can build. Good luck.

Comment: @catlin, I added a few additions for you, it let's you add a name for yourself, then you can chose someone to chat to. It will add the relevant names to the chat from there onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within external commands, using CMD's `set` replace.

```
set /p "thing=thing (a variable for user input) "

if not "%thing%"=="%thing:o=_%"  echo Contains 'o'
```

With that, you are replacing the content of *`%thing%`* temporary to `_` and then check if both strings are equal.

If the replace matches 0 results, then strings will be equal and it will not show anything. If some string is replaced, strings will not match so it will contain the character.